# Rails Has Two and With Many

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I'm working on a Rails 4 App where there is a model called Apps. Each App can have multiple certificates which are stored in the Certificates model. Out of the certificates each App can have a development and a production certificate which are then active for the current App. At a single given time only two certificates (development/production) can be active for the App. I'm trying to come up with an ActiveRecord structure for this logic but I'm lost. Any suggestions on this?

```
Apps (Has Many certificates)
  - development_certificate
  - production_certificate

Certificates (Belongs to App)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution that more closely models your data is simply two one-to-one relationships:

```
class App < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :production_certificate, class_name: "Certificate"
  belongs_to :development_certificate, class_name: "Certificate"
end
```

Comment: Thanks i'm going to be using this, do i need to do any extra setup to the models or should i add certain fields?

Comment: Your `App` models needs a `production_certificate_id` and a `development_certificate_id`. That's about it.

Answer (score 1):

Well, put 2 boolean values on your model. One for `development` and one for `production`. Then create a custom validator that checks on creation, if there is a `development` or a `production` certificate active for this app. Also you could create two scopes to get this certificates more easily.
You don't need to overthink it, or model it in some crazy way.

Comment: Thank you for this, In my certificates model every new certificate is automatically classified as a development certificate which can be changed by editing the certificate in the view and changing it to production. With that being said the above won't work tho if each certificate is already classified to an environment but not designed for use by a specific app? That being said is there a workaround for this?

Comment: Well, then one `app` has just one `certificate` for each type. @meagar answer is the right one.